# How to correctly utilise redux-saga putResolve

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to sequence my API calls so that I can call an endpoint, wait for it to succeed, then select the required value out of the state.

I'm very new to redux-saga and am finding it difficult to understand how to achieve this!

What I've tried:

So we try and block whilst we perform an API call:

```
const resp = yield putResolve(assistantActions.fetchSustainability());
```

Later in the code we select the updated value out of the state:

```
const assistant = yield select(getAssistant);
```

The action that is called looks like:

```
export const fetchSustainability = () => ({ type: FETCH_SUSTAINABILITY });
```

In the saga we:

```
yield takeEvery(FETCH_SUSTAINABILITY, fetchSustainability);
```

Then the function returns a promise:

```
function fetchSustainability() {
    return axios.get(`${url}/sustainability`);
}
```

I'm not sure that I've set this up any where near right as I've made lots of changes trying to get it working!

The select statement executes immediately and as the call isn't blocked the state isn't updated correctly.

Is my approach correct? If not is someone able to provide a simple working example on how to achieve a blocking call.

Answer (score 1):

So the second parameter to `takeEvery` needs to be a generator function;

within that you can call your `fetchSustainability`

```
function* generator() {
   yield call(fetchSustainability); // calls the actual function
}

// in the saga
yield takeEvery(FETCH_SUSTAINABILITY, generator);
```

your action `fetchSustainability` should return a Promise.

Here's an example to highlight the difference between put and putResolve.

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-saga-example-x77jb
The example uses `thunkMiddleware`

Comment: axios get is not retruning a Promise?

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer. It is indeed returning a promise